# Threads executing an operation a second

Tags: multithreading, c++11, cout

I'm trying to create a concurrent code where I execute a function per second, this function prints a character and waits a second on that thread. The behaviour I expect is to print each character after another but this doesn't happen, instead, it prints all of the characters of the inner loop execution. I'm not sure if this is somewhat related to an I/O operation or whatnot.

I've also tried to create an array of threads where each thread are created on the execution of the inner loop but the behaviour repeats, even if not calling `join()`. What might be wrong with the code?

The following code is what I've tried to do, and I used a clock to see if it was waiting the correct amount of time

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <string>

void print_char();

int main() {

    using Timer = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
    using te    = std::chrono::duration<double>;
    using s     = std::chrono::seconds;

    te interval;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        auto  a = Timer::now();
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {

            std::thread t(print_char);
            t.join();
        }
        auto b = Timer::now();
        interval = b-a;

        std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<s>(interval).count();
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

        return 0;
}

void print_char() {
    std::cout << "*";
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *The behaviour I expect is to print each character after another but this doesn't happen, instead, it prints all of the characters of the inner loop execution.*

You need to flush the output stream in order to see the text:

```
std::cout << "*" << std::flush;
```

`std::endl` contains call to `std::flush` in it and this is why you see whole lines to be displayed once the inner loop is complete. Your threads do add the `'*'` characters once per second, you just don't see them being added until the stream is flushed.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the code

```
std::thread t(print_char);
t.join();
```

The first line creates and start a thread. The second line immediately wait for the thread to end. That makes your program *serial* and not parallel. In fact, it's no different than calling the function directly instead of creating the thread.

If you want to have the thread operate in parallel and independently from your main thread, you should have the loop in the thread function itself instead. Perhaps something like

```
std::atomic<bool> keep_running = true;

void print_char() {
    while (keep_running) {
        std::cout << "*";
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    }
}
```

Then in the `main` function you just create the thread, and do something else until you want the thread to end.

```
std::thread t(print_char);

// Do something else...

keep_running = false;
t.join();
```

---

In regard to your current code, it's really no different than

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    auto  a = Timer::now();
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        print_char();
    }
    auto b = Timer::now();
    interval = b-a;

    std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<s>(interval).count();
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: The intent of my code is to show each character one second after another using threads. Then it makes sense to use `join()` as I want to wait one second after creating another thread to print the character, right? It is a serial execution but waiting one second at a time.

Comment: Even if I remove the threaded code and call the function directly, waiting one second in the main thread does not resolve the issue, unfortunately. It prints one line after (waiting `j` seconds to print the line) other instead of one character at a time.

Comment: @RafaelCamposNunes The thread function I show, with the loop, will show the character once every second, as long as it is running. If you just want to show a character every second for a certain amount of time, why bother with threads to begin with? The threads in your code makes no sense.

Comment: That is right, threads in this context doesn't make much sense but this is an assignment and I have to deal with threads in this context. I think that the problem might be on the I/O side? I gonna try to desynchronize the I/O.